# How to add MySql library into Code::Blocks/MinGW

Tags: mysql, c, mingw, codeblocks

I need to create a C program that requires a MySQL database. For this, I've seen on the web that I need to use a MySQL connector (which I installed in my PC). I run my code with Code::Blocks/mingw and I don't know how to add the mysql libraries to it.

To connect to a MySQL database I need the mysql.h file (I have the file but I don't know where to place it in my computer). Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using mingw, then from mingw installer you should find the support for MySQL library. If it doesn't appear there, then you can download the MySQL-devel source tarball and then compile and install it with mingw (you need GCC and other software building tools installed). In this way you'll get support of mysqllib support in mingw like GNU/Linux environment.